# AirFlick Error: VLC not found

Tags: mac, appletv, streaming, vlc

I'm trying to play videos from my Mac to my Apple TV and am getting the error "cannot proceed. vlc not found".  I've tried running older versions of the software and updating VLC both to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

linked from: [Can I stream any video played with VLC player to Apple TV?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23412/can-i-stream-any-video-played-with-vlc-player-to-apple-tv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many apps that rely on VLC require it to be location in the Applications folder.

If you've moved VLC or renamed it, try putting it back.